# Possible to force https only on AWS Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-lightsail

I am using an AWS Lightsail Load Balancer in conjunction with another Lightsail ec2 instance so that I can use the free certificate manager built into the Lightsail Load Balancer. This seems to automatically forward all traffic from my Load Balancer to my ec2 nginx server on `port 80` so that the following config also supports `https` connections:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mountainviewwebtech.ca www.mountainviewwebtech.ca;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

However, when I add the following lines to ensure that `http` redirects to `https`, I receive the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` as my ec2-instance is only receiving traffic on `port 80` even when using a secure connection so it just keeps redirecting over and over again.

```
if ($scheme != https) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Is there anyway to obtain the original `$scheme` before it was forwarded to my ec2 instance?

Comment: Shouldn't the test be `if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") { ...`?  The balancer should be setting `X-Forwarded-Proto` on the incoming request.  I don't know that `$scheme` is viable, here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This fixed my problem so that `https` is enforced now, but I'm running into something that may be a problem now. What seems to be happening is that every single request (even those for static assets) are being redirected to `https` which i'm not sure if this is a good practice or not. 1 thing I do know which sucks is that the Google Page Insight Tools cant even analyze my website due to the number of redirects `https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmountainviewwebtech.ca%2F`. I wonder if I just need a CDN now or modify config more

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a 'free' SSL cert, using Let's Encrypt's CertBot will get you there (and save you money). I have had good success with this option.

Using the load balancer as the SSL terminator ends the secure connection at the load balancer. Thus un-encrypted traffic is sent from the balancer to the compute instances (port 80). If you want to forward SSL traffic to the compute instances, see if the load balancer will do port forwarding. This being Lightsail I doubt it will be possible.